# Corner Radius on UIToolbar?

Tags: swift

I have a view with a corner radius.  I've added a toolbar at the bottom of the view.  The toolbar has hard edges so the corner radius is not visible.

Is there anyway to add a corner radius to the toolbar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add

```
self.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

to the view with the corner radius.